# How to stop a StreamingContext in Apache Spark on Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils
import sqlContext.implicits._

val ehParams = Map[String, String](
    "eventhubs.policyname" -> "Full",
...
)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val stream = EventHubsUtils.createUnionStream(ssc, ehParams)
val cr = stream.window(Seconds(6))

case class Message(msg: String)
stream.map(msg=>Message(new String(msg))).foreachRDD(rdd=>rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("temp"))

stream.print
ssc.start
```

---

This above starts and runs fine but I cannot seem to stop it. Any call to %sql show tables will just freeze.

How do i stop the StreamingContext above ?

Comment: Not sure why below 2 answers are down-voted... But you can stop streaming context with ssc.stop(true) and/or ssc.stop(true, true) or whatever your choice is or was

Answer (score 6):

`ssc.stop` also kills the Spark Context, requiring an interpreter restart.

Use `ssc.stop(stopSparkContext=false, stopGracefully=true)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`ssc.stop` in a new paragraph should stop it

There is also an ongoing [discussion in the dev@ mailing list](http://markmail.org/thread/d2mvl6lp3grhstzz) on how to improve integration with streaming platforms.